# how do i include my footer.html in my base.html

Tags: django, django-templates

can somebody help me how to include a page in base html.because i just wondering whether i have to define the url and also in view.py.because all example i have checked in stackflow non is working for me because i have tried all of them.
    TemplateDoesNotExist at /

```
includes/footer.html

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.11
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

includes/footer.html

Exception Location:     /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py in find_template, line 148
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.13
Python Path:    

['/home/harrugg2/projects/django/membersite',
 '/usr/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 27 Apr 2017 15:50:50 +0300
```

this my base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>member site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                    <!-- Core CSS - Include with every page -->
       <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'css/Footer.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
         <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
                        <!--div class="page-header"-->
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Member site</a>
                            </div>
                             <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                             </form>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                                <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                                  <li role="presentation"><a href=class="glyphicon glyphicon-chat>Messages <span class="badge">3</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>     
                            <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">Hello Welcome {{ user.username }} </div>                               
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                                    
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">More Functions
                                            <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}">Add New Post</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="{% url 'post_draft_list' %}">Post Draft list</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile Settings</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="divider"></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="divider"></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                {% else %}
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                                    
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Login
                                            <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="{% url 'login' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>login Here</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                {% endif %}
                    </nav>
            <div class="content container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}

                    <!-- Core Scripts - Include with every page -->
                    <script src = "{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>

                    <script src = "{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

                {% block javascript %}
                {% endblock %} 

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <!--footer region --> 
    <footer>
      <a href="{% include "includes/footer.html" %}"></a>
    </footer>       
    </body>
 </html>
```

this my footer.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content">
</div>
    <footer id="myFooter">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 myCols">
                    <h5>Get started</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 myCols">
                    <h5>About us</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Company Information</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 myCols">
                    <h5>Support</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Help desk</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 myCols">
                    <h5>Legal</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="social-networks">
            <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright">
            <p>© 2017 Copyright Text </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
{% include "includes/footer.html" %}    
{% endblock %}
```

the project layout

```
├── blog
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── 0002_comment.py
│   │   ├── 0002_comment.pyc
│   │   ├── 0003_auto_20170222_1938.py
│   │   ├── 0003_auto_20170222_1938.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   └── static
│   │       ├── css
│   │       │   ├── blog.css
│   │       │   └── bootstrap.min.css
│   │       └── js
│   │           ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │           └── jquery.min.js
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   ├── blog.css
│   │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   │   └── footer.css
│   │   └── js
│   │       ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │       └── jquery.min.js
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── blog
│   │   │   ├── add_comment_to_post.html
│   │   │   ├── base.html
│   │   │   ├── includes
│   │   │   │   ├── footer.html
│   │   │   │   ├── footer.php
│   │   │   │   └── sidebar.html
│   │   │   ├── post_detail.html
│   │   │   ├── post_draft_list.html
│   │   │   ├── post_edit.html
│   │   │   └── post_list.html
│   │   └── registration
│   │       ├── change_password.html
│   │       ├── edit_profile.html
│   │       ├── login.html
│   │       ├── logout.html
│   │       ├── profile.html
│   │       ├── register.html
│   │       └── success.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── chat
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   └── views.py
├── database
│   └── dump.sql
├── data.json
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── membersite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── middleware.py
│   ├── middleware.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
└── README.md
```

this setting.py

```
"""
Django settings for membersite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'pl&$yewh^89&^af=hgchr!4$8k&dv^gkluc(ndj3j&4$blks8s'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.pythonanywhere.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    #'membersite.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'membersite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'membersite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases   
# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Nairobi'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
#LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/account/'
#LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/base/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
#LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'base_url'
#LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/templates/blog/base.html/'
#BASE_REDIRECT_URL = '/templates/blog/base.html/'
#BASE_REDIRECT_URL = '/account/'
#BASE_DIR = '/templates/blog/base.html/'
#LOGIN_URL = '/blog/base.html/'
LOGIN_URL = '/account/login/'
#LOGIN_URL = '/account/'
#LOGIN_URL = '/'
LOGIN_EXEMPT_URL = (
    r'^account/logout/$',
    r'^account/register/$'
    )

EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
```

Comment: It's telling you the template includes/footer.html *does not exist*. Does it actually exist? Is it in that directory?

Comment: yah the footer.html is in the folder called includes.that where it is stored

Comment: Please show your file layout, and the TEMPLATES dict in your settings.py

Comment: @DanielRoseman i have included settings.py

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to comment because of low rep, however i believe the runtime error you're receiving is because you have both:

- `{% include "includes/footer.html" %}` (in your base.html)
- `{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}` (in your footer.html)

This setup seems to initiate a circular dependency issue.

Comment: I understand that you don't have enough rep to comment, but please don't post comments as answers. We've all been there; just build up rep first.

Answer (score 1):

Your template appears to be in 'blog/includes/footer.html'; you should use that in your include tag.

Comment: Well, you should probably fix that.

Comment: `RuntimeError at /`

`maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` this the error i am getting.

Answer (score 0):

You're including footer.html in footer.html. Don't do that.

Answer (score -1):

Change your include to following:

```
<div class="footer">
 {% include "includes/footer.html" %}    
</div>
```